# Dart: Replace content inside file using RandomAccessFile

Tags: dart, dart-io

I am trying to replace content inside a file using RandomAccessFile class of "dart".
My file content is : `Hello user World`
My dart code is:

```
import 'dart:io';

main() async{
  File file = File("test/testraf.txt");
  RandomAccessFile raf = await file.open(mode: FileMode.writeOnly);
  var f1 = await raf.setPosition(7);
  f1.writeString("John");
  f1.close();
}
```

I am trying to replace **user** with **John**.
But above code corrupts my file and do not do the intended work.
This is what I intended to do : `Hello John World`
How do I replace content inside a file using random writes ?

Is it possible, my requirement is to replace data at random position inside a file, without creating another copy of the file ?

Answer (score 3):

ok So guys the problem was file mode must be : `FileMode.writeOnlyAppend`.
The working code will be :

```
import 'dart:io';

main() async{
  //File content: Hello user World
  File file = File("test/testraf.txt");
  RandomAccessFile raf = await file.open(mode: FileMode.writeOnlyAppend);
  var f1 = await raf.setPosition(6);
  await f1.writeString("John");
  await f1.close();
}
```

So it will output :  `Hello John World`

Comment: thank you so much. But how can this work for flutter web because I have this error Uncaught Error: Unsupported operation: _Namespace